# How can we create hyper link text in QtGui?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to display some hyperlink text in my window so that it will respond to user click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [QLabel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlabel.html) supports HTML markup and can easily be added to any QWidget.

Another easy way to do this is to have a borderless flat [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qpushbutton.html).

Comment: Does we don't have any special class for hyperlink text in QtGui?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using QLabel. QLabel::setOpenExternalLinks(bool) and you have to set the  text of the label to be in html format text

Comment: but does it will respond to click event just like if we want to call a slot while clicking that text. can you give example.

Comment: can you specify more detail about it i have tried the above but it is not responding click event.